# Unable to update git config: failed to lock file [home]/snap/gitkraken/137/.gitconfig.lock' for writing:

Tags: git-config, gitkraken

So I installed the latest version of Gitkraken(v5.02) and wanted to try the new gpg key feature. Firstly, the documentation says that if you have an existing key, gitkraken will automatically use it, but mine doesn't.

Also, when in the gpg settings menu, I chose the sign commits by default option,
[image]

I get the following error:
[image]

Though I tried deleting the .gitconfig.lock file and even reinstalled gitkraken, I can't get it to work.

Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: I installed gitkraken using snap:

```
sudo snap install gitkraken
```

Comment: I'm getting this same thing with the version from their website (not snap). Before I had the snap version and I didn't get this error, but I couldn't use the gpg program.

Comment: Which os are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10. Recent installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on the gitkraken help slack channel. They suggested using the .deb installer instead of snap. It worked exactly as expected.

The .deb installer fixes both the auto-detection of gpg keys problem as well as the "failed to lock file problem".

In the same chat, someone else responded that snap probably was n't working properly due to the issue of sandboxing.

The issue with snap may be solved in more recent updates from gitkraken.